# Unable to hit Server with soap envelop and method name

Tags: iphone, ipad, wsdl

> Error with connection Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002
>   "unsupported URL" UserInfo=0x6a3f420
>   {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http%3A%2F%2F10.101.189.65%3A8090%2Fbusinessservice.svc,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=http%3A%2F%2F10.101.189.65%3A8090%2Fbusinessservice.svc,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x6a3f450
>   "unsupported URL"}

I am getting this error when i am hitting the server.

Its directly calling the didfailwithError.
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

```
NSLog(@"Error with connection %@",error);
```

}

May i know when this error call!

I create soapenvelope and call soap request with method name.  and encoded the url and send to the dot.net webserver

```
NSString *soapMessage = [self getTestSoapEnvelope];
NSLog(@"soapMessage %@",soapMessage);

NSString *urlString = @"http://systemName:8090/businessservice.svc";
NSString *encodeUrl = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)
CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                    (__bridge_retained CFStringRef)urlString,
                                    NULL,
                                    (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                    kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:encodeUrl];    
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: @"ManageCase" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if( theConnection )
    {
        webData = [NSMutableData data];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
    }
```

And the Request time is GET

Unable to hit the server.  Please any one advice me with this issue.

@thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are encoding the full URL:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://systemName:8090/businessservice.svc";
NSString *encodeUrl = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)
CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, ...
```

while you should only encode the last URI portion (the one containing arguments etc.).

In your case you do not actually need encoding your URL because there is no such part as:

```
@"?param=1&url=newsite.com&title=Post title";
```

Just pass `urlString` to `URWithString`:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://systemName:8090/businessservice.svc";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

Comment: Thanks for replay!  i try without encoding i got same error. (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

NSLog(@"Error with connection %@",error);
}

Comment: Error with connection Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=303 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303.)" UserInfo=0x6a37870 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://systemName:8090/businessservice.svc, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://systemName:8090/businessservice.svc}

Comment: as you can see, this is a completely different kind of error. This seems to be related to a bug in NSURLMutableRequest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469061/nsurlrequest-cannot-handle-http-body-when-method-is-not-post

Comment: for this error is that i am missing any forHTTPHeaderField need to send!