# Cannot set HTTP request body

Tags: iphone, ios, http

Can anyone tell me how to send a file to server and a username. I tried to set HTTP body with the content of the file and use GET method to set username but it doesn't work and encounter the exact situation as this post:( this is a bug) :

[NSURLRequest cannot handle HTTP body when method is not POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469061/nsurlrequest-cannot-handle-http-body-when-method-is-not-post)
As the post says, can anyone show me how to use PUT method as in both the ios client and php server or show me another method ?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/978061/643383

Comment: This all depends on the webservice you are calling.  Is it expecting a GET or POST or PUT request?

Comment: Actually I am trying to send a xml to the server together with the username, which is the best way to it? Can anyone show me some sample code for both server (php) and ios client